# set the period for DatetimeIndex to calculate and plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have such a series named "data_grouped".

```
action_time
2017-02-16 00:00:00    23
2017-02-16 00:00:01    24
2017-02-16 00:00:02    22
2017-02-16 00:00:03    18
2017-02-16 00:00:04    20
2017-02-16 00:00:05    24
2017-02-16 00:00:06    16
2017-02-16 00:00:07    13
2017-02-16 00:00:08    18
2017-02-16 00:00:09    20
2017-02-16 00:00:10    16
2017-02-16 00:00:11    22
2017-02-16 00:00:12    22
2017-02-16 00:00:13     9
2017-02-16 00:00:14    13
2017-02-16 00:00:15    23
2017-02-16 00:00:16    18
2017-02-16 00:00:17    13
2017-02-16 00:00:18    18
2017-02-16 00:00:19    19
2017-02-16 00:00:20    20
2017-02-16 00:00:21    24
2017-02-16 00:00:22    19
2017-02-16 00:00:23    24
2017-02-16 00:00:24    24
2017-02-16 00:00:25    24
2017-02-16 00:00:26    15
2017-02-16 00:00:27    28
2017-02-16 00:00:28    19
2017-02-16 00:00:29    27
                       ..
2017-02-16 23:59:30    27
2017-02-16 23:59:31    21
2017-02-16 23:59:32    27
2017-02-16 23:59:33    21
2017-02-16 23:59:34    20
2017-02-16 23:59:35    21
2017-02-16 23:59:36    18
2017-02-16 23:59:37    30
2017-02-16 23:59:38    16
2017-02-16 23:59:39    24
2017-02-16 23:59:40    19
2017-02-16 23:59:41    34
2017-02-16 23:59:42    24
2017-02-16 23:59:43    23
2017-02-16 23:59:44    29
2017-02-16 23:59:45    23
2017-02-16 23:59:46    28
2017-02-16 23:59:47    16
2017-02-16 23:59:48    32
2017-02-16 23:59:49    22
2017-02-16 23:59:50    26
2017-02-16 23:59:51    25
2017-02-16 23:59:52    27
2017-02-16 23:59:53    36
2017-02-16 23:59:54    26
2017-02-16 23:59:55    22
2017-02-16 23:59:56    22
2017-02-16 23:59:57    27
2017-02-16 23:59:58    19
2017-02-16 23:59:59    20
Name: action_type, Length: 85913, dtype: int64
```

The index is DatetimeIndex. The DatetimeIndex is from "2017-02-16 00:00:00" to "2017-02-16 23:59:59". I want to do a aggregate the sum for every hour. And plot it with the horizontal-axis is the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) + aggregating function `sum` + [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
s.resample('H').sum().plot()
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) + [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).sum().plot()
```

Comment: It's not a Dataframe,it's a Series. So I should transform it to the a Dataframe first?

Comment: It works and looks much better than what I did before.Thanks,@jezrael

Comment: Super. Do you need `mean` ? Or `sum` ?

Comment: I've changed it to sum myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145681/discussion-between-chunk-ning-and-jezrael).